# Black screen on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an openGL program that drawn 3 houses and another things but, when I compile with gcc, just appears a black screen - and this is happening with all my openGL programs

What can I do?

PS: If I resize my screen, the drawn appears.

OS: macOS Mojave
PC: MacBook Air 2017

Development in Visual Studio Code

gcc version: 10.0.0

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979324
//teto

bool teto = true;
bool base = true;
bool janela = true;
bool porta = true;

void Teto(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(20.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(40.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}
void Base(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 30.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(35.0, 30.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(35.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}

void Porta(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(5.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}

void Janela()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 5.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}

void Sun()
{
    static float R = 10.0; // Radius of circle.
    static float X = 20.0; // X-coordinate of center of circle.
    static float Y = 70.0; // Y-coordinate of center of circle.
    static int numVertices = 30; // Number of vertices on circle.
   float t = 0; // Angle parameter.
   int i;

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a line loop with vertices at equal angles apart on a circle
   // with center at (X, Y) and radius R, The vertices are colored randomly.
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
      for(i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i)
      {
         glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
         glVertex3f(X + R * cos(t), Y + R * sin(t), 0.0);
         t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
      }
   glEnd();
}
// Drawing routine.
void drawHouse(void)
{
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    //glPopMatrix();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Sun();
    glTranslatef(30.0f,30.0f,0.0f);
    if(teto)
        Teto();
    glTranslatef(3.0f,-30.0f,0.0f);
    if(base)
        Base();
    glTranslatef(15.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(porta)
        Porta();
    glTranslatef(-10.0f,20.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();
    glTranslatef(20.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();


    glPopMatrix();
    glScalef(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f); 
    glTranslatef(3.0f,30.0f,0.0f);
    if(teto)
        Teto();
    glTranslatef(3.0f,-30.0f,0.0f);
    if(base)
        Base();
    glTranslatef(15.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(porta)
        Porta();
    glTranslatef(-10.0f,20.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();
    glTranslatef(20.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();


    glPopMatrix();
    glScalef(1.75f, 1.75f, 0.0f);
    glScalef(1.25f, 1.25f, 0.0f);
    //glScalef(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f); 
    glTranslatef(25.0f,20.0f,0.0f);
    if(teto)
        Teto();
    glTranslatef(3.0f,-30.0f,0.0f);
    if(base)
        Base();
    glTranslatef(15.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(porta)
        Porta();
    glTranslatef(-10.0f,20.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();
    glTranslatef(20.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(janela)
        Janela();
    glFlush();


}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 130.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case 27:
            exit(0);
            break;
        case 'c':
            base = !base;
            break;
        case 't':
            teto = !teto;
            break;
        case 'j':
            janela = !janela;
            break;
        case 'p':
            porta = !porta;
            break;
        case 's':
            Sun();
            //glRotatef(10.0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 700);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("House.cpp");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawHouse);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);  
    setup(); 
    glutMainLoop();  
}
```

Comment: Same thing. Nothing happens

Comment: Sorry. I'm using clang, not gcc

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: replace `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` . You are not cleaning the depth buffer. After the first iteration, the back buffer swaps with the front buffer, and since the depth is going to be the same, it will discard all incomming fragments after the first frame